# How to find the MLE of μ and Σ when there are 4 jointly normally distributed variables in a csv file? (using R)

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution

Problem:
Take a something.csv dataset which contains many variables. The dataset contains the following set of variables X=[popularity, duration_sec, chords, loud]<sup>T</sup> (<sup>T</sup> implying transpose). If **these four variables are all jointly normally distributed**, how would you compute the MLE (maximum likelihood estimate) of μ and Σ? Do this by using the programming language R.

So I know that two random variables X and Y are said to be jointly normal, if aX+bY has a normal distribution for all a,b∈R. This counts for a=0 and b=1 or reversed. If X∼N(μX,σ<sup>2</sup><sub>X</sub>) and Y∼N(μY,σ<sup>2</sup><sub>Y</sub>) are independent then in this case, they are jointly normal. Being independent is the same as uncorrelated for jointly random variables. So then X+Y∼N(μX+μY,σ<sup>2</sup>X+σ<sup>2</sup>Y+2ρ(X,Y)σXσY).

As, in my case, there are 4 random variables: (X<sub>1</sub>) popularity, (X<sub>2</sub>) duration_sec, (X<sub>3</sub>) chords, (X<sub>4</sub>) loudness. It is assumed that they are jointly normal. So aX<sub>1</sub> + bX<sub>2</sub> + cX<sub>3</sub> + dX<sub>4</sub> has a normal distribution for all a,b,c,d∈R. So the X<sub>1</sub>∼N(μX<sub>1</sub>,σ<sup>2</sup>X<sub>1</sub>) X<sub>2</sub>∼N(μX<sub>2</sub>,σ<sup>2</sup>X<sub>2</sub>) X<sub>3</sub>∼N(μX<sub>3</sub>,σ<sup>2</sup>X<sub>3</sub>) X<sub>4</sub>∼N(μX<sub>4</sub>,σ<sup>2</sup>X<sub>4</sub>) are independent and thus uncorrelated **as** they are jointly normal. So then X<sub>1</sub>+X<sub>2</sub>+X<sub>3</sub>+X<sub>4</sub>∼N(μX<sub>1</sub>+μX<sub>2</sub>+μX<sub>3</sub>+μX<sub>4</sub>,σ2X<sub>1</sub>+σ2X<sub>2</sub>+σ2X<sub>3</sub>+σ2X<sub>4</sub>+2ρ(X,Y)σXσY)

The multivariate normal distribution for the 4-dimensional vector X=[popularity (X<sub>1</sub>), duration_sec(X<sub>2</sub>), chords(X<sub>3</sub>), loud(X<sub>4</sub>)]^T is X~*N*(μ,Σ). where μ=[E(X<sub>1</sub>), E(X<sub>2</sub>), E(X<sub>3</sub>), E(X<sub>4</sub>)]<sup>T</sup> and  Σi,j= E[(X<sub>1</sub>-μ<sub>1</sub>)(X<sub>2</sub>-μ<sub>2</sub>)(X<sub>3</sub>-μ<sub>3</sub>)(X<sub>4</sub>-μ<sub>4</sub>)] = Cov[X<sub>1</sub>,X<sub>2</sub>,X<sub>3</sub>,X<sub>4</sub>].

Now to apply this to R coding...
I know how to read a csv and select the needed columns (variables). I also now how to calculate the mean and variance of a column but I don't think that is what is asked. So, I don't know what to do from here. So how to compute the MLE of μ (4th dimensional mean vector) and Σ (4x4 covariance matrix) from selected columns.

To see what kind of data we are working with, here is a little part of the dataset (only 10 out of 800 rows) :

```
structure(list(popul = c(61L, 57L, 65L, 72L, 66L, 48L, 53L, 37L, 
45L, 65L), duration_sec = c(250.96, 273.88, 260.44, 213.507, 
322, 228.413, 221.653, 129.613, 260.2, 199.853), chordnum = c(2L, 
2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L), loudness = c(-7.799, -7.342, 
-8.832, -5.137, -7.079, -5.631, -9.57, -8.271, -6.485, -3.74)), 
row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  However, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to do your homework *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve problems you encounter whilst *doing it for yourself*. "You must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself. The question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." For more detail, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Comment: Greetings! Its much easier to help you if we have some form of data to work with. Please provide a reproducible dataset, such as using the `dput` command and sharing the output here. You can learn how to do so here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg